# Ultimate Member plugin issue wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member

Iam using Ultimate Member Plugin to register,login user form front end with using dashboard iam setting role subscriber for teacher by changing name Tutor and for Student i have changed name of author to be Student with slugs remain default. Now i have set estriction for subscriber when register will be approved by admin and for student i have set restriction auto approval in this case user will be register but his role is none so i have created another role student with slug student it will count user in other category and shows role type none. Iam using member type dropdown values tutor and author in ultimate member register form wordpress.

[image: User Role For User Register as Student]